# how to replace element contents with new html without loosing javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do is replace the contents of $('#product_blocks')  with new html while preserving the jQuery listeners events on a similar element id.

```
var thenewhtml= '<div id="clickme">hello this text will be replace on click</div>';

$('#product_blocks').html(thenewhtml);
```

the jquery event:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {

$("#clickme").html("yayImChanged");

});
```

BUT my problem is once I replace #products_block with new html, $("#clickme" ) does not work.. does not carry forward to new html...  This is what I'm looking to solve.

Comment: You are confusing jquery and javascript. Javascript has innerHTML method whose equivalent in jquery is .html

Comment: Replace $("#product_blocks").innerHTML(thenewhtml); with $("#product_blocks").html('<span id="userclickedhere">new data</span>');

Comment: hi but my jquery function is not working with id="userclickedhere". when it's replaced.

Comment: @ASH which jquery function are you talking about? you have to be specific in your details

Comment: First you have to write a click fn 
$(document).on('click','#userclickedhere',function(e){  //Your code here  });

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt hi I updated my question.

Comment: By updating, you removed your html I suppose?

Comment: yes, I rephrased  what im asking for. most answers were not what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery .on()` method signature for defining event handlers e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '#userclickedhere', yourClickHandlerFunction);
```

[jQuery .on() doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)

Updated Answer:
It will still work.

```
$(document).on('click', '#clickme', function(e) {
  $(this).html("yayImChanged");
});
```

[Here is a CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/prithvi/pen/MxqBKa)

Answer (score 1):

Because the page structure looks the same - it's only the content of the `span` that's been changed - you can select the *new* content of the span, and replace the old span's content with it:

```js
const $userclickedhere = $('#userclickedhere');
$userclickedhere.on('click', () => console.log('click'));

const thenewhtml = `<span id="userclickedhere">new data</span>`
const newSpanContent = $(thenewhtml).text();
$userclickedhere.text(newSpanContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product_blocks">  <span id="userclickedhere">click me</span> </div>
```

This will preserve any listeners on `#userclickedhere`.

(of course, you also need to use `.html` on jQuery collections to set their HTML - `.innerHTML` is a method *on native DOM elements*, which are not the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified):

```js
const newHtml = '<div id="clickme">hello this text will be replace on click</div>';
const attachEventClickHandler = () => $('#clickme').one('click', () => {
  console.log('Clicked...');
  $('#product_blocks').html(newHtml);
  $('#clickme').on('click', () => {
    console.log('yayImChanged...');
    $('#clickme').html('yayImChanged');
  });
});
$('#product_blocks').one('DOMSubtreeModified', () => attachEventClickHandler());
attachEventClickHandler();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="product_blocks"> <span id="clickme">click me</span> </div>
```

Comment: Udated answer using developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified

Answer (score 0):

When jQuery registers an event, it looks for that selector in DOM. it will only register events for only available DOM elements.

Here, you are adding **thenewhtml** later the jQuery registered the events.
Hence, you have to register click event on #clickme again once after you replace the HTML. just after the line: $('#product_blocks').html(thenewhtml);

This is the flow of jQuery click event on particular selector.

But, there's also an another way to register events on those html elements which do not exist in DOM when page load.
i.e. $(document).on() method.

here you can do it both the ways.
1. define click event after replacing html in #product_blocks.
2. define click event using $(document).on() anywhere.

```
$(document).on('click','#clickme',function() {
     /* your code here */
});
```

or

```
$('#product_blocks').html(thenewhtml);
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $(this).html("yayImChanged");    
});
```